# Asynchronous Function Error In Dart-Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

So I'm trying to create a simple Sign In page in Flutter using `Google Firebase` but Firebase is not giving me desired output. Maybe its error in `Asynchronous Function` cause its giving me output `Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'`

Code for Anonymously Sign In dart file:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Future signAnonymous() async {
    try {
      AuthResult result = await _auth.signInAnonymously();
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;
      return user; 
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Sign In Page Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:freezeria/Screens/services/auth.dart';

class signin extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _signinState createState() => _signinState();
}

class _signinState extends State<signin> {
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.purple[300],
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.purple[600],
        elevation: 0.0,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('Sign In To Freezeria!'),
      ),
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 50.0),
          child: ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('SignIn'),
            style: ButtonStyle(
              backgroundColor:
                  MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.purple[100]),
            ),
            onPressed: () async {
              dynamic result = _auth.signAnonymous();
              if (result == null) {
                print("Error Signing In");
              } else {
                print('Signed In');
                print(result);
              }
            }
          )
       ),
    );
  }
}
```

The Output I got was:

```
I/flutter ( 8533): Signed In
I/flutter ( 8533): Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'
```

I need to get user details provided by the firebase

Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

_auth.signAnonymous() is an async function, for that matter it returns a Future !  Use the **await** keyword to get the user value instead of a Future object !

```
result = await _auth.signAnonymous();
```